# Typescript Lambda

Tags: typescript

New to Typescript and seeking some improvements for the following code to find an application available language from the browser language preference.

```
@Component
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  ...
  created() {
   const lang = findLang();
   ...
  }
  ...
} 
function findLang(): string {
  for(const lang of navigator.languages ) {
    if (lang.startsWith('en')) {
      return 'en';
    }
    if (lang.startsWith('es')) {
      return 'es';
    }
   }
   return 'en';
}
```

I can think of a few improvements above the code without a success. Moving the findLang function to the Foo class. It works functionally but falls on the test (npm test). Also, it would be better to have a lambda instead of a function or method as the function is used only once. But the code

```
const lang = navigator.languages.forEach( l =>  { 
    if (l.startsWith('en')) {
      return 'en';
    }
    if (l.startsWith('es')) {
      return 'es';
    }
  }
);
```

yields blank value.

How to make those improvements?

Comment: If you write a lambda and use curly braces `{` and `}` you are required to use the `return` keyword to return something. 

As for your other question, if you want to get recommendations on how to improve something, you should try to explain what you perceive as being wrong.

I wouldn't use a class if all you need is a function, and your 1-liner definitely seems less legible than the multi-line version.

Comment: I just edit the lambda code. I also edit the post to address the reason for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it as it is.

One major surprise you see already is that `forEach` isn't returning anything, which is correct: [`forEach` has an `undefined` return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). To apply a lambda to each value in an array, you want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead....but even then you would wind up with an array with some `undefined` results, which you would then need to filter and return the first value of. It won't get you the short-circuiting behavior that your `return` with a loop will get you.

Comment: Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1):

To me it makes more sense to define class methods since you already have the class. If that works, but the test fails, isn't the problem with the test?

```
@Component
export default class Foo extends Vue {
  ...
  created() {
   const lang = this.findLang();
  }
  findLang(): string {
    for(const lang of navigator.languages ) {
      if (lang.startsWith('en')) {
        return 'en';
      }
      if (lang.startsWith('es')) {
        return 'es';
      }
     }
   return 'en';
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I just learn that I have to use "this" to refer to a method in the class in Typescript.